# How to free WPF resources after they are no longer being used

Tags: wpf, resources

I use a default image as a user avatar the first time my application is loaded. After that, the user can change their avatar. The problem is that after using a new avatar, the user cannot delete the old avatar. They get the error message: `"file access denied"`. That means my application is still using the old image somewhere, but I don't know where.

My question is: How do I free the WPF resource after using it? I have looked around with Google, but found nothing.

Please help me!

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some code of how you load the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually have to call `Dispose()` on class instances after use to free resources. Even better is to use the `using` statement that implicitly calls `Dispose()` like this:

```
using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    // Load file content
}
```